# How to resume playing from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, playback, resume, internet-radio

I am making an online radio station app. The app works good.
My radio doesn't resume after the call is ended. And I have to restart it again.

Here is my code:

```
    void MyAudioSessionInterruptionListener(void *inClientData, UInt32 inInterruptionState)
    {
        ShoutcastAudioStreamer *radio = (ShoutcastAudioStreamer*)inClientData;
        if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionBeginInterruption) {
            [radio stop];
            NSLog(@"kAudioSessionBeginInterruption");
        }
        else if (inInterruptionState == kAudioSessionEndInterruption) {
        //  [radio start]; // this doesn't work - radio is gone
;
        }
    }
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score -1):

similar questions were found, but without reply too...

[Do not get the AudioListenerInterruptionEnd trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3785632/751932)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/8819315/751932

Probably it can help you.